# Mathematical notation for the least value a function can give

Tags: notation

I have a set with unknown cardinality. The cardinality can be from a number a to a number b.
How can I indicate the number a (or b)?

The question in texts is:
"What is the least value of n(A)"
(A is a set with a few possible cardinalities)
How can I properly express this in mathematical notation? I used the notation(If you call it a "notation") `least of n(A)`

I have seen this question:
[Mathematical notation for the maximum of a set of function values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40861/mathematical-notation-for-the-maximum-of-a-set-of-function-values)

The things that differ is that I need the notation to express  the minimum (or max) number a function can give for a constant x, not the min (max) for a range of x

Also, the set of all possible sets isn't given and is there to be found out by the question solver. (as it implies, each solver may generate a different one)

`n(A)` is the cardinality of the set `A`

I do not have a strong mathematical background. so please avoid very confusing notations. thanks in advance

Comment: The least value in a set $S$ (assuming that one exists) is denoted by $\min S$. So the least value of the set $n(A)$ is $\min n(A)$. Another common notation is $$\min_{a \in A} n(a)$$ which is used especially when $n$ is defined implicitly by some expression, for example, $\min_{x \in [-1,1]} x^2 + 2$.

Comment: In your case of cardinality of $A$ (traditionally denoted by $|A|$), you need to identify the collection $\scr A$ of all sets $A$ over which you are taking the minimum. Then it would be $$\min_{A\in\mathscr A} |A|$$

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer; but the problem is that the set collection  (I didn't know how to type that notation) is to be found out by the question solver. I edited the question to include this

Comment: What about simply "Let $\alpha$ be the least possible value of $n(A)$?" There is no need to decorate the notation (here, I'm using $\alpha)$ with all the various things it depends on unless you're using the notation in a situation where the collection of $A$'s can vary within the same discussion. If you're simply dealing the statement of a problem that you're going to give the solution to, I think just picking something like $\alpha$ and saying precisely what it represents is enough.

Comment: The problem is with RTL languages and my inability to translate mathematical contents into English (as evident from the question I posted) @DaveL.Renfro (I'm going to text the problem). thanks for the time you spent.

Comment: Your problem doesn't make sense, now. How can you talk about a minimum, if you do not know what it is a minimum of? If you do not know what sets you are taking the cardinalities of, then there is no minimum cardinality to talk about.